# How do I move SharePoint Lists including metadata

Tags: 2013, powershell, export, import, content-migration

on sharepoint 2013 on-prem, I would like to migrate a a few lists in the same site collection to a different subsite using powershell. I tried the following commands:

```
Export-SPWeb "SiteURL" -ItemUrl "ItemUrl" -Path "PathToExportFile" -IncludeVersions All -IncludeUserSecurity

Import-SPWeb "NewSiteURL" -Path "PathToExportFile"
```

The list was migrated with no issues, it also kept versioning, but I didn't manage to maintain metadata such us **Modified, Created, Modified by** etc.

Is it possible to migrate the list using the above method and at the same time maintaining the metadata of the lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the import command, I had to append -IncludeUserSecurity:

```
Import-SPWeb "NewSiteURL" -Path "PathToExportFile" -IncludeUserSecurity
```